# How to show a modal on a new window using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so I was trying to show modal on a new window until now I use

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

which show it as a customize window , but I want to open a new browser window and  print the modal inside it.

I want to do this because if I just use `modal('show');` and my parent page refreshes in the background, (*I am using  `window.location.reload(true);` to refresh the parent page, that's why it closes the modal, I couldn't find how to refresh the whole parent page using ajax*) it will close the modal window and I don't want this.

Is there any function that I can use to open the modal on a new window?

Comment: why you are not call this in page load?

Comment: because i need to call a javascript function and passe data to the modal and show it i .

Comment: and i can see how to test if the open was opend or not to just show it everytime i reload

Comment: you can refer link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847454/make-any-links-in-a-bootstrap-modal-open-in-a-new-window if this can help you

Answer (score 0):

**i have created 2 file;**
**file 1 has this code,**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="window.open('file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/a.html'); ">Open Modal</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**and 2nd file has this code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#myModal").modal();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

for this is working, try this.